# To what accuracy are the local variables displayed in the Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2 debugger? Apparently 1 is not equal to 1

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Take the following record:

```
TVector2D = record
  public
    class operator Equal(const V1, V2: TVector2D): Boolean;
    class operator Multiply(const D: Accuracy; const V: TVector2D): TVector2D;
    class operator Divide(const V: TVector2D; const D: Accuracy): TVector2D;
    class function New(const x, y: Accuracy): TVector2D; static;
    function Magnitude: Accuracy;
    function Normalised: TVector2D;
  public
    x, y: Accuracy;
  end;
```

With the methods defined as:

```
class operator TVector2D.Equal(const V1, V2: TVector2D): Boolean;
  var
    A, B: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := (V1.x = V2.x) and (V1.y = V2.y);
  end;

  class operator TVector2D.Multiply(const D: Accuracy; const V: TVector2D): TVector2D;
  begin
    Result.x := D*V.x;
    Result.y := D*V.y;
  end;

  class operator TVector2D.Divide(const V: TVector2D; const D: Accuracy): TVector2D;
  begin
    Result := (1.0/D)*V;
  end;

  class function TVector2D.New(const x, y: Accuracy): TVector2D;
  begin
    Result.x := x;
    Result.y := y;
  end;

  function TVector2D.Magnitude;
  begin
    RESULT := Sqrt(x*x + y*y);
  end;

  function TVector2D.Normalised: TVector2D;
  begin
    Result := Self/Magnitude;
  end;
```

and a constant:

```
  const
    jHat2D : TVector2D = (x: 0; y: 1);
```

I would expect the `Boolean` value of `(jHat2D = TVector2D.New(0,0.707).Normalised)` to be `True`. Yet it comes out as `False`.

In the debugger `TVector2D.New(0,0.707).Normalised.y` shows as exactly `1`.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9XhQqgD.png]

It cannot be the case that this is exactly 1, otherwise the `Boolean` value of `(jHat2D = TVector2D.New(0,0.707).Normalised)` would be `True`.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

`Accuracy` is a `Type` defined as: `Accuracy = Double`

Comment: Suggested reading: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html and https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

Comment: That  advice is incomplete. = can be fine. And SameValue is weird.

Comment: @David - SameValue is only weird with Epsilon's of 0, otherwise it makes perfect sense (where 'weird = "why does it work the way it does when Epsilon = 0 ?".  There may be a good reason, but it's not immediately obvious).  Meanwhile, nobody is actually addressing the question, which is not [directly] about floating point precision in code but the *representation by the debugger* of the values involved.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - 99.9% certain.  The debugger shows v1.x = 0, v2.x = 0 v1.y = 1 and v2.y = 1.  This representation cannot be correct if B = FALSE since this indicates that v1.Y is not equal to v2.Y, contradicting  the debug visualization of these values.  Conclusion:  v1.y and v2.y are equal to or  *approximately* 1, but not actually equal to each other and the representation of these values as "1" by the debugger is incorrect for at least one of these values.

Comment: Use a watch and specify the accuracy

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: and how do you specify the accuracy, you mean Digits edit box?

Comment: @David - watches of floating point/decimal value suffer the same problem, even with maximum accuracy (by which I presume you mean "Digits" since there is no other mechanism to control 'accuracy').  See my answer: you need to contrive a memory dump (you can't directly watch an expression such as (@v1.y)^)

Comment: @Deltics: watching the value in XE7 as floating point shows 0,999999999999999889 with 18 digits for V2.Y

Comment: @whosrdaddy - oops, yes.  Quite right.  It seems when I tried changing the watch settings for v2.y I must have missed with my click and changed v1 again without realising.

Comment: I just type `realvar, F18` into the watch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that **Accuracy** is a synonym for a **Double** type, this is a bug in the visualization of floating point values by the debugger.  Due to the inherent problems with internal representation of floating points, **v1.Y** and **v2.Y** have *very slightly* different values, though both approximate to 1.

Add watches for **v1.y** and **v2.y**.  Ensure that these watch values are configured to represent as "Floating Point" values with Digits set to 18 for maximum detail.

At your breakpoint you will see that:

```
v1.y      = 1
v2.y      = 0.999999999999999889
```

(**whosrdaddy** provided the above short version in the comments on the question, but I am retaining the long form of my investigation - see below the line after **Conclusion** - as it may prove useful in other, similar circumstances as well as being of potential interest)

### Conclusion

Whilst the debugger visualizations are strictly speaking incorrect (or at best misleading), they are never-the-less *very almost* correct.  :)

The question then is whether you require **strict** accuracy or accuracy *to within a certain tolerance*.  If the latter then you can adopt the use of **SameValue()** with an **EPSILON** defined suitable to the degree of accuracy you require.

Otherwise you must accept that when debugging your code you cannot rely on the debugger to represent the values involved in your debugging to the degree of accuracy relied on in the code itself.

**Option: Customise the Debug Visualization Itself**

Alternatively you may wish to investigate [creating a custom debug visualisation](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40268) for your **TVector2D** type to represent your x/y values to the accuracy employed in your code.

For such a visualization using **FloatToStr()**, use **Format()** with a **%f** format specifier with a suitable number of decimal places.  e.g. the below call yields the result obtained by watching the variable as described above:

```
Format('%.18f', [v2.y]);

// Yields  0.999999999999999889
```

---

### Long Version of Original Investigation

I modified the **Equal** operator to allow me to inspect the internal representation of the two values **v1.y** and **v2.y**:

```
type
  PAccuracy = Accuracy;

class operator TVector2D.Equal(const V1, V2: TVector2D): Boolean;
var
  A, B: Boolean;
  ay, by: PAccuracy;
begin
  ay := @V1.y;
  by := @V2.y;

  A := (V1.x = V2.x);
  B := (V1.y = V2.y);

  result := A and B;
end;
```

By setting watches in the debugger to provide a *Memory Dump* of **ay^** and **by^** we see that the two values are represented internally very differently:

```
v1.y   : $3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00
v2.y   : $3f ef ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

**NOTE:** Byte order is reversed in the watch value results, as compared to the actual values above, due to the Little Endian nature of Intel.

We can then test the hypothesis by passing **Doubles** with these internal representations into **FloatToStr()**:

```
var
  a: Double;
  b: Double;
  ai: Int64 absolute a;
  bi: Int64 absolute b;

begin
  ai := $3ff0000000000000;
  bi := $3fefffffffffffff;

  s := FloatToStr(a) + ' = ' + FloatToStr(b);

  // Yields 's' = '1 = 1';
end;
```

We can conclude therefore that the evaluation of **B** is correct.  **v1.y** and **v2.y** *are* different.  The representation of the **Double** values by the debugger is incorrect (or at best misleading).

By changing the expression for **B** to use **SameValue()** we can determine the deviation between the values involved:

```
uses
  Math;

const
  EPSILON = 0.1;

B := SameValue(V1.y, V2.y, EPSILON);
```

By progressively reducing the value of **EPSILON**  we find that **v1.y** and **v2.y** differ by an amount less than **0.000000000000001** since:

```
EPSILON = 0.000000000000001;   // Yields B = TRUE
EPSILON = 0.0000000000000001;  // Yields B = FALSE
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem stems from the fact that the 2 floating point values are not 100% equal and that the Debug Inspector rounds the floating point, to see the real value you need add a watch and specify floating point as visualizer:

[image]

[image]

Using the memory dump visualizer also reveals the difference between the 2 values:

[image]